# Setting up small business network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am trying to set up networking for a small business (about 15–20 employees). Most of the computers are wired, but a wireless access point is needed too.

I was thinking of a scheme like this (click to enlarge):

[image]

It this the correct way of connecting?

Should router and firewall be separate hardware components?

Comment: Have a look at http://routerboard.com/ they have good router and AP components. But no sutible switch, but if you only going to use basic stuff any switch will do.

Comment: Shouldn't you **put your web server outside the firewall** if is meant to be publicly accessible?

Comment: No, you just have to forward ports (80 for http) on NAT (router) to web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you have there as far as clients and servers, that will work fine. If it was me I would remove the router, and just use a bigger switch. You don't need a separate firewall, however I would highly recommend it. Your client OS, and server OS have built in firewalls, and also routers have them too.

Comment: In my case router is needed because of NAT. Do you have any experience with Draytek's Vigor rotuers?

Comment: @mata I do not have any experience with that brand. NAT is a standard, so it should be configured about the same on any device.